# CodeBuild unable to fetch an S3 object despite having Administrator Access

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am unable to do a code build due to this error. I could not make any sense of this error.

It is suppose to use `aws/codebuild/docker:17.09.0` to build me a docker image to be pushed to ECS. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using VPC configuration for this project. Please check if the private subnet provided to CodeBuild had a NAT (can access Internet) or you have an s3 VPC endpoint set up for this. To confirm that VPC configuration is the issue, you can run a build with no VPC, before troubleshooting the VPC's route to access s3 for your builds.